# Receving Google Speech streaming result when SingleUtterance equals true

Tags: foreach, google-cloud-platform, audio-streaming, google-cloud-speech, cancellation-token

I am using the Google Speech API to transcribe streaming audio. I would like to receive the result transcript. I set `MaxAlternatives = 0` so I won't receive interim results, only the final transcription result. I also set `SingleUtterance = true`. My understanding is that I will get the first response as `SpeechEventType = EndOfSingleUtterance` and then the second and final response will contain the results, where I can access the transcription. Below is the code I have tested (slightly adapted from the docs: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize). However, the two `foreach` loops are not very elegant and I imagine would only be necessary if `InterimResults = true`. So how can I receive the single transcription result from a streaming request as described above? I notice that there is about three seconds between when I finish talking, and when the transcript is received so I think that there is something wrong with how I am reading the results.

```
while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(default(CancellationToken)))
{
    foreach (var result in streamingCall.ResponseStream.Current.Results)
    {
        foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
            {
                //Do stuff with alternatvie.Transcript
            }
    }
}
```